# console object is not working when variable console

Tags: javascript, variables, console

```js
 window.onload = function () {
        var console = null; 
        console.log(1);
    }
```

When I run that js code,find this error

> Uncaught TypeError: console is not a function

I know the Object console is Overwritten by variable ，but how can I resolve the problem, I don't want to change the variable console.

Comment: Actually you haven't overridden the console object, you've shadowed it with a local variable. Use `window.console` to refer the original console in that function.

Comment: Or just don't name your variable `console`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you don't want to "change" the "variable" `console`, don't. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
 window.onload = function () {
        test_console();
    }

    var console = null;

    function test_console() {
        window.console.log(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`window.console.log('something')`

this work because all global object are in window;

Comment: I tried the window,but when the `window.console.log` run in the following code ,the same problem happened `window.onload = function () {
            test_console();
        }

        var console = null;

        function test_console() {
            window.console.log(1);
        }`

Comment: is because the variable console is declared outside the function, you could any way save the console function before the variable declaration like this `var newConsole = console; var console = something; newConsole.log()`

Answer (score -2):

window.console will get you the object, however, if you're using IE and you don't have the Developer Tools window open console will not return anything.

Comment: for old ie versions

Comment: This is true for IE 11 which is the latest version.

Comment: @oscar Nope, this was fixed in IE10.